Dynamic disable Input fields in reactive form
I am using dynamic validation from @rxweb/reactive-form-validators. Here is an example on Stackblitz.
Is there a way to dynamically disable a field based on the value of another field?
Do you have any suggestions for implementing dynamic field disabling in a reactive form?

For me, the best idea it's use a Directive, see, e.g. this SO

Validations do not involve disable enable, You have to use traditional methods to disable/enable, like subscribing to valueChanges observable or performing the update on (input) event. Working example below.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  RxFormBuilder,
  FormBuilderConfiguration,
} from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-info-add',
  templateUrl: './user-info-add.component.html',
})
export class UserInfoAddComponent implements OnInit {
  userInfoFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get('assets/dynamic-validation.json')
      .subscribe((dynamicValidationConfiguration: any) => {
        this.userInfoFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            firstName: ['James'],
            lastName: new FormControl({ value: 'Mani', disabled: true }),
          },
          new FormBuilderConfiguration({
            dynamicValidation: dynamicValidationConfiguration,
          })
        );
      });
  }

  disabledValidation() {
    const { firstName } = this.userInfoFormGroup.value;
    const lastNameCtrl = this.userInfoFormGroup.get('lastName');
    if (firstName === 'James') {
      lastNameCtrl.disable();
    } else {
      lastNameCtrl.enable();
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
